# Clear input on focus with jQuery and return on blur

Tags: jquery

This almost works. However, when leaving the field "defaulttext" appears rather than the original text value. Not sure how to most efficiently echo the variable inside defaultText.

```
$(function() {
    var defaultText = $(this).val();
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
      $(this).val('');
      });
     $('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
      $(this).val('defaultText');
      echo 
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$(function() {
    var input = $('input[type=text]');

    input.focus(function() {
         $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function() {
         var el = $(this);

         /* use the elements title attribute to store the 
            default text - or the new HTML5 standard of using
            the 'data-' prefix i.e.: data-default="some default" */
         if(el.val() == '')
             el.val(el.attr('title'));
    });
 });
```

---

**Update**

Browsers are progressively implementing the `placeholder` attribute, which provides the ability to display a "hint" to the user.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder

Comment: +1 for actually fixing the logic errors in the OP's code, not just the one syntax error.

Comment: Of all the answers this one works, but requires you to use the title attribute. Is there a way to do it without a title? So any site I use the snippet on, any input fields with values will erase on focus and come back on exit? Even if the site doesn't have a title tag on all inputs?

Comment: use your own attribute - preferably using the HTML5 standard of `data-`

Comment: If you can't/won't change the HTML markup then you'll need to create a simple dictionary with controls id's and default text...

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the ' ' marks around the defaultText variable in your set method (val).

Try something along hte lines of

```
$(function() {
    var defaultText = '';
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
        defaultText = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
        $(this).val(defaultText); // NB removed the ' ' marks
        //echo // What are you trying to echo? 
     });
 });
```

Comment: Hmm ok I will fix it when I get home. Cheers for letting me know

Answer (score 2):

This solution requires jQuery!

I wrapped this functionality up in a utils module like so:

```
var utils = (function () {
    var utils = {};
    //some other properties...
    utils.setupAutoclearInputs = function() {
        $('.input-autoclear').each(function() {
            $(this).data('default', $(this).val()).addClass('gray');
        }).focus(function(e) {
            if (!($(this).val() !== $(this).data('default'))) {
                $(this).removeClass('gray').addClass('black').data('modified', true).val('');
            }
        }).blur(function(e) {
            if (!($(this).val() !== $(this).data('default')) || $(this).val() === '') {
                $(this).removeClass('black').addClass('gray').val($(this).data('default'));
            }
        });
    }
    //some other methods...
    return utils;
}());
```

In the HTML:

Add: `class="input-autoclear"` to each input you wish to be included.

Set the default value: `<input ... value="defaultValue" ... >`

Create some css classes for gray and black text or whatever you want.

Personally I'm using `.gray { ... }` and `.black { ... }` but you might want better names.

Finally:

Fire the utils modules method using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    utils.setupAutoclearInputs();
    ...
}
```

Make sure the code for the module lives outside the document.ready call and you will probably want it in the global scope of your application.

For more on proper javascript module writing, visit this [article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth).

Answer (score 2):

This one will save the default text for you using the .data() function. So no need for extra markup.

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    if (!$(this).data("DefaultText")) $(this).data("DefaultText", $(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() == $(this).data("DefaultText")) $(this).val("");
}).blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).val($(this).data("DefaultText"));
});
```

Comment: After you submit the form and push back in the browser, it doesn't work right. It uses whatever value you entered on the previous submission as the default text, so if you clear it and click off of it, it doesn't use the original DefaultText. Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Simpl write `$(this).val(defaultText):` without the ''s else it wont treat it as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 attribute **placeholder** on each input tag, eg:

```
<input type="text" value="original text value" placeholder="default value" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I funetuned this code little bit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var defaultText = '';
    $('.input-focus-clear').focus(function () {
        defaultText = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $('.input-focus-clear').blur(function () {
        var newText = $(this).val();
        if (newText.length < 1) {
           $(this).val(defaultText);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not referencing the variable `defaultText`. You're passing a string since it's wrapped in quotes.

```
$(function() {
    var defaultText = $('input[type=text]').val();
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
      $(this).val('');
      });
     $('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
      $(this).val(defaultText); // fixed!
      });
 });
```

Comment: With this, the text never returns on exit.

Comment: Sorry, fixed now. You were using the `this` keyword improperly to access the value for the variable `defaultText`. If you need help understanding the `this` keyword, here is a good resource: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your firebug:

```
$(function() { console.log($(this)) });
```

You will find out that

```
var defaultText = $(this).val();
```

is probably not what you want.

If initial value for the input is the default text, obtain it like this:

```
var defaultText = $('input[type=text]').val()
```

Be aware, that this will work correctly only if there is just one input text on your page.

And also remove quotes in:

```
$(this).val('defaultText');
```

Comment: Thanks. Though since webpages can have multiple inputs wouldn't be practical for me in real use, but thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = $('#q');
q.focus(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-default') == $(this).val()) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('data-default'));
    }
});


<input type="text" name="q" id="q" data-default="Search..." value="Search..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.myclass').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).css('color', '#666'); // this could be in the style sheet instead
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
            $(this).css('color', '#333');
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            $(this).css('color', '#666');
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
<input type="text" class="myclass" size="30" value="type here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working! I use it myself:

```
/* Forminputs löschen und wiederherstellen */
jQuery(function() {
    var input = jQuery('#userForm input[type=text], #userForm textarea');

    input.focus(function() {

        jQuery(this).attr('data-default', jQuery(this).val());
        jQuery(this).val('');

    }).blur(function() {
        var el = jQuery(this);

        if (el.val() == '')
            el.val(el.attr('data-default'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("input[type=text]").focus(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-old-input", $(this).val());
        $(this).val("");

    });

    $("input[type=text]").blur(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("data-old-input"));
        $(this).attr("data-old-input", "");
    });
```